# Imprime la primera aparición de una cadena en otra pero solo si es el primer caracter o la última palabra

Tags: c, ensamblador

Al correr el programa pide una cadena la cual se guardara en una cadena1 y pedirá otra que se guardara en cadena2. El programa debe de buscar la primera aparición de la cadena 1 en la cadena 2, el detalle es que lo hace solo en 2 situaciones:

- la primera cuando es cadena1: "hola"
- la segunda cuando es cadena2: "hola"
  Aquí imprime que encontró la cadena en la posición: 1

La segunda es cuando son los últimos caracteres:

- la primera cuando es cadena1: "todos los finales"
- la segunda cuando es cadena2: "Al parecer tenemos que hacer todos los finales"
  Aquí imprime que encontró la cadena en la posición: 29

Pero si pongo:

- la primera cuando es cadena1: "hay que saltar"
- la segunda cuando es cadena2: "Mira entre todos hay que saltar muy alto"
  Aquí me imprime que no encontró la cadena 1 en la cadena 2 cuando debería de salir que sí salió en la posición 18

El procesador que uso para el ensamblador es el 80386 con una UBUNTU.

```x86asm
;--ENSAMBLADOR

;VARIABLES INICIALIZADAS

section .data
    
;------------------------------------------------------------------
;VARIABLES NO INICIALIZADAS

section .bss
    
;------------------------------------------------------------------
;SECCIONES GLOBALES

section .text

    global remove_dup:
    
;------------------------------------------------------------------
;NOMBRE DEL PROGRAMA

remove_dup:;Inicio de programa

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp    ;Protocolo de entrada
    
;------------------------------------------------------------------
    
;PUSH's

    push esi
    push ebx
    push ecx                        ;Contador de veces que itera EBX
    push edx
    
;------------------------------------------------------------------

    ;RECIBIR PARAMETROS
    mov esi, [ebp + 8]          ;Recibe la 1ra. cadena que buscare en la 2da. cadena
    mov ebx, [ebp + 12]     ;Recibe la 2da. cadena
    
;------------------------------------------------------------------ 

    ;PROGRAMA
    xor eax, eax
    xor edx, edx
    xor ecx, ecx
    
.cicloPrimero:

    mov dl, byte [esi]          ;Le paso un caracter de la primera cadena a BL
    
.ciclo:

    cmp byte [ebx], 0           ;Pregunto si la 2da. cadena no llego al final
    je .finMalo
    
    inc ecx                         ;El contador de posiciones donde encontro la cadena
    
    cmp byte [ebx], dl          ;Pregunto si el caracter en EBX es el primer caracter de ESI
    je .verifica
    
    inc ebx                         ;Siguiente letra de EBX
    jmp .ciclo
    
.verifica:

    inc esi                             ;Incremento ambos registros para apuntar a la siguient letra
    inc ebx
    
    cmp byte [esi], 0               ;Comparo si la 1ra. cadena ya llego a su fin, lo que me indica que termino de leer todo
    je .finBueno
    
    mov dl, byte [esi]          ;Le paso la siguiente letra a DL
    
    cmp byte [ebx], dl          ;Pregunto si ambas letras son iguales
    je .verifica
    jmp .noIgual
    
.noIgual:

    mov esi, [ebp + 8]          ;Vuelvo a poner el inicio de la cadena en ESI
    mov ebx, [ebp + 12]     ;Vuelvo a poner el inicio de la cadena en EBX
    add ebx, ecx                    ;Sumo las posiciones que llevo a ebx para no empezar desde 0
    inc ebx                         ;Incremento en 1 para puntar una letra despues y no se cicle infinitamente
    jmp .cicloPrimero

;------------------------------------------------------------------
    
.finMalo:

    mov eax, 0FFFFFFFFh ;Como llego a fin de cadena entonces le 
    jmp .fin
    
.finBueno:
    mov eax, ecx
    
.fin:

;------------------------------------------------------------------

    ;POP's
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    
;------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    pop ebp
    ret

;---- Codigo C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LONG 90

extern int remove_dup (char str1[], char str2[]);

int main ()
{

    char cadena1[LONG], cadena2[LONG];
    int valor;
    
    printf("Ingrese una cadena a buscar en la siguiente cadena: ");
    fgets(cadena1, LONG, stdin);
    
    printf("Ingrese una cadena larga: ");
    fgets(cadena2, LONG, stdin);
    
    valor = remove_dup(cadena1, cadena2);
    
    if(valor == -1)
    {
        printf("La primera cadena no esta en la segunda cadena.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("La 1ra. Cadena esta en la posicion -> %d <- de la 2da. Cadena.", valor);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace tu función `remove_dup`?? Inserta más código, sino poco podremos hacer

Comment: remove_dup recibe 2 cadenas, la primera cadena se buscara su primera aparición en la segunda cadena, tengo entendido que todo el código esta visible tanto en ensamblador y en C, es un interfazado entre ambos lenguajes.